# Не работает конструкция

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

Здравствуйте! В первый раз столкнулся с такой конструкцией, как она называется и почему не работает:

```
nero_type result = [i, j] (nero_type temp1, nero_type temp2)->nero_type
                        {
                            temp1 = 10*i;
                            temp2 = 20*j;
                            return temp1+temp2;
                        };  //nero_type типа int
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Называется это лямбда-выражением, но

1. что-то она странно у вас написана - зачем ей параметры, которые ей не нужны? :)
2. вы присваиваете `result` саму функцию, а не результат ее работы.

Думаю, что вы хотели на самом деле

```
int result = [](int i, int j){ return 10*i+20*j;}(i,j);
```

[Вот](http://ideone.com/icRtnV):

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int i = 10, j = 20;
    int result = [](int i, int j){ return 10*i+20*j;}(i,j);
    std::cout << result << std::endl;
}
```

**Update**

Ну, вот я расписал, что есть что в вашей лямбда-функции

```
 val = std::accumulate(begin(src_images), 
                       end(src_images), 
                       koef_t(0.0), 

     [i, j] // Захватываются значения внешних переменных `i` и `j`
     (koef_t old_val, const neurons_line &image) // параметры функции
     -> koef_t // тип возвращаемого значения (обычно не нужен, выводится из `return`)
     { return old_val + (image[i] * image[j]); } // Тело функции
                     );
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! А в квадратных скобках, что должно быть? И еще смущает (i,j). 
Можете, пожалуйста, объяснить лямбда выражение здесь:
val = std::accumulate(begin(src_images), end(src_images), koef_t(0.0), [i, j] (koef_t old_val, const neurons_line &image) -> koef_t{
    return old_val + (image[i] * image[j]);
   });

Comment: Я расписал ее в ответе. В квадратных скобках - внешние значения (или ссылки), чтобы ими можно было пользоваться внутри функции. Типа, есть переменная, которая не передается как параметр, но должна участвовать в вычислении...

Comment: Спасибо!!! А почему нельзя так написать, как в этом примере? Параметры там просто так для проверки, i и j передаем и возвращаем ответ в переменную result. А вылазит ошибка, что <lambda> нельзя к int привести(nero_type): 
nero_type result = [i, j] (nero_type temp1, nero_type temp2)->nero_type
                        {
                            temp1 = 10*i;
                            temp2 = 20*j;
                            return temp1+temp2;
                        };

Comment: Потому что типом лямбда-функции является функтор, уникальный для каждого выражения, а не nero_type, как у вас. И соответственно, чтобы объявить лямбду необходимо использовать auto или шаблоны.

Comment: Ну я же написал в ответе - "*вы присваиваете result саму функцию, а не результат ее работы*". Чтобы вызвать - добавьте передачу РЕАЛЬНЫХ параметров в скобках. Типа `nero_type result = [i, j] (nero_type temp1, nero_type temp2)->nero_type
                        {
                            temp1 = 10*i;
                            temp2 = 20*j;
                            return temp1+temp2;
                        }(0,5);`  Грубо говоря, у вас написано `result = function;`, а надо - `result = function(7,8);`...

Comment: В примере который с accumulate там возвращается результат работы функции, хотя он не имеет в конце передачи параметров

Comment: Я разобрался, там просто функцию передать нужно было, спасибо большое Harry!!!